# Responsive image to cover whole page

Tags: html, css, image, sass, responsive-design

i am trying to add image to my website page to cover whole page in any screen size

```css
*{
         padding:0px;
         margin:0px;
         }
         img {
             width:100%;
         object-fit:cover;
         max-width: 100%;
         min-height: 100%;
         min-width: 100%;
         }
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<div class="responsive">
            <a href="#" ><img src="img/d.png"> </a>
         </div>
```

The code work good for desktop but for mobile, some images are not covering 100% width of the screen.

Comment: Check the `min-width` and `max-width` styles for the image. And check the size of the image relative the to screen size of the phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

body should have some height and width inorder for image to inherit height from the parent. By using % in unit, it means relative to parent. And so, parent element should also have width and height.

```
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.responsive {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: what is the meaning of `vh` and why you used vh in body and % in class

Comment: vh is viewport height (height of the screen either phone or laptop)

Comment: why one place you using `vh` and in other place using `%`

Comment: Because its a parent all html tags. And its a choice we can use anyone. But sometimes % is better and sometimes vh. Generally we use vh for full height elements.

Comment: Ok, got it. So i have to use your 2 CSS along with my 2 CSS. right?

Comment: What is 2 css ?

Comment: My two CSS in above mentioned in my question. one with `*` and another for `img` tag. And your css for `body` and `class`. So, in total 4 rulees